# Digitising Hedgerows as line or polygon?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, digitizing

I have been tasked with digitising hedgerows for a 5x5km area in Wales.

As hedgerows are linear features, and thus do not have a wide diameter, would digitising each  hedgerow as a line be appropriate or should they be digitised as a polygon?

Comment: It will depend on what you are going to use the data for.

Comment: I'd digitise them as lines, but add half the width as an attribute, so you might buffer the hedges if necessary.

Comment: Is it important to know if hedgerow is 1 or 2 meters wide? If it is not, digitize as lines. It works quite well with roads, for example. Having width as an attribute is usable idea. Or could it make sense to classify the hedgerows to narrow, medium, or wide?

Comment: Many thanks for the responses. I will digitize them as lines.

Comment: Before you waste your time spending hours digitising hedgerows I would suggest you spent some time looking at OS MasterMap. If you are an academic you can download that from edina digimap if your institution subscribes to it. That dataset captures field boundaries which in most cases are hedgerows. Also if by a stroke of luck you happen to been working on the Gower look [here](https://www.esdm.co.uk/gower-hedgerow-mapping).

Answer (score 1):

The guidance comes from the tasker. If your using line features as for location or polygons for area and location analytics. Resolution and shadows will come into play when area is required.